# Easy accessible variable that isn't in the Global scope

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am building a game with the CreateJS library. In the current build I save a lot of my variables and objects in the Global scope, which is really neat and makes it easy for various extended classes to reuse SpriteSheets etc.

I am looking for a way to NOT use the global scope. Obviously I can pass the spritesheet, or a class which contains the spritesheet as a parameter to all displayobjects I make, but I was hoping there was a more clever way of doing this.

Any suggestions or tips on how to achieve this would be helpful.

Comment: you still can use an object that hold all these resources at global scope

Comment: Hi, I was hoping to find a way to not use the global scope at all. I don't want users to be able to access anything using the console.

Comment: anything can be accessed through the console.

Comment: I dont know if this would help but you can bind all functions inside a main function and you can define all variables here. This will prevent contamination of global space and these values will still be available to all functions. [Reference fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/afxj6v6f/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a **module**:

```
var main = (function(){
    var myPrivateVal1 = "Something";
    var myPrivateVal2 = 56;
    var myVeryPrivateVal = 3;

    //Return only what you want to expose
    return {
        myPublicVal: 123,
        getVal1: function(){
            return myPrivateVal1;   
        },
        getVal2: function(){
            return myPrivateVal2;   
        },
        doCalculation: function(){
            return myVeryPrivateVal * myPrivateVal2;
        }
    }
})();

console.log(main.myPublicVal); //123
console.log(main.myPrivateVal1); //undefined
console.log(main.myPrivateVal2); //undefined
console.log(main.myVeryPrivateVal); //undefined

console.log(main.getVal1()); //Something
console.log(main.getVal2()); //56
console.log(main.doCalculation()); //168
```

Here you have one global variable **main**, which is the module that exposes what you need to expose, but still keeps track of the variables needed.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/xou26pev/1/) JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. Yea so the issue is that any user would essentially be able to just do main.getVal1() or whatever.

I have been reading up on this the past day, and it doesn't really look like there is a way to do what i want in a manageable way.

Comment: Yeah but the point is you don't have to expose `getVal1()` if you don't want to. And a user can't go `main.myPrivateVal1 = "New value";`. Anyway, if you do this, and in the end **minify** your code, i'd say you're pretty safe.

Comment: true. I was thinking of using a MVC pattern to build my game, which would mean that i'd have different 'classes' needing to access data. A way could be to pass the data as a parameter to the class, but I was just hoping to find a solution where that wasnt' needed.

Comment: Debugger can still have access to all these "private" variables, only have to add a breakpoint inside one of these public function, and change the values.Cant say that you're safe